# Trying to understand inline assembly code in C

Tags: c, gcc, x86-64, inline-assembly

So I have some code

```
#define umul_ppmm(w1, w0, u, v)                         \
  asm ("mulq %3"                                        \
       : "=a" (w0), "=d" (w1)                           \
       : "0" ((uint64_t)(u)), "rm" ((uint64_t)(v)))
```

I'm trying to debug it and understand how it works.

Currently, I am looking at [This pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/15213-s07/misc/asm64-handout.pdf) for reference on `mulq`.

My understanding so far is that it is multiplying two 64 bit numbers together which would be `w0` and `u`. Then it stores the result of that multiplication in `w0` and `w1`.

My main questions are:

1. According to [This GCC assembly guide on Simple Constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html#Simple-Constraints) 'a' and 'd' in `"=a"` and `"=d"` are address and data registers respectively. How does that play in here and what exactly does that mean?
2. What does `"0"` mean in this case? That same guide says that "An operand that matches the specified operand number is allowed." What would be the matching operand here?
3. How does `v` come into play? If at all?

Printing out the variables before and after the function call results in

> w1         w0           u                    v
>
> 2097147    549755813889 17179869183          4611684961865433149
>
> 4294966311 17179869183  13835060159816138691 4611684961865433149

Comment: Are you compiling for a 68k-derived architecture? If not, why do you think `a` and `d` are address and data registers? Why do you think `wl` (which isn't even defined) is an input?

Comment: @EOF Is there anyway I can determine if my architecture is derived from 68k? Also, in the definition for mulq it stated `mulq S` has the effect of `R[%rdx]:R%rax] <- S*R[%rax]` I guess I wrongfully assumed rax was part of the multiplication.

Comment: @EOF I meant `w0` instead of `w1` in my intial post, but I see my mistake now. I also mistook `%3` to mean `u` instead of `v`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The `mulq` instruction implicitly produces result in the `a` and `d` registers (normally known as `rax` and `rdx`)
2. Operands are indexed from zero. `"0"` thus means same place as the first operand, which is `w0`. `mulq` implicitly uses `rax` as one of the input operands, hence the matching constraint. Could have written it out as `"a"` again.
3. `v` is the operand `%3` which is the only explicit operand referenced in the `mulq` instruction. The code multiplies `u` and `v` so of course it "comes into play".

You printed the registers wrong, on the second line you swapped `w0` and `u`, as `u` and `v` are unchanged input operands.
`u*v=w1*2^64+w0`, that is `17179869183*4611684961865433149=4294966311*2^64+13835060159816138691`